# Extjs Automatic form grid / binding

Tags: user-interface, extjs, code-reuse

this is this ausom [row editor](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/row-editing.html) tool in ext js.
[image]
I am looking for more complex tool for grid and actual form.
Something with good API so I can give the user the abillity to see the from in full screen, and not just in a row.
Something that will help me building more and more CRUDs without recreating the forms  again and again.
something like "form renderer" from settings.

Where can I get this kind of API.
Thanks

Comment: What form are you talking about? Do you want the columns of the grid to open up in a form?

Comment: @Varun Achar - Exactly, for fast CRUDing

Comment: I don't think opening up a form just for editing a row is a good idea, unless the grid only shows a subset of the data.. Opening up a form for editing would only increase user clicks, which is irritating.. Also, editing with the row editor will be much faster, since you can configure the row editor for something like `ctrl + enter` for save etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in "form-renderers" but you can create analog using form's [loadRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord) method.
First of all you create form with the same set of inputs as form's `columns` (obviously, you can do it dynamicaly). For example if your `columns` config looks like this:

```
columns: [
    {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name'},
    {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1},
    {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
],
```

your form's config should look like this:

```
Ext.define('ux.FormEditor', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.formeditor',
    title : 'Edit User',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'name',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name'
                },{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'email',
                    fieldLabel: 'Email'
                },{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'phone',
                    fieldLabel: 'Phone'
                }]
        }];

        this.buttons = [{
                text: 'Save',
                action: 'save'
            },{
                text: 'Cancel',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.close
            }];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Now you assign handler for grid's `itemdblclick` event:

```
yourGrid.on('itemdblclick', function(grid, record) {
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit'),
        form = view.down('form');

    form.loadRecord(record);
    view.down('button[action=save]').on('click', function(btn) {
        var rec = form.getRecord(),
            values = form.getValues();

        rec.set(values);
        view.close();
    });
});
```